# how to show $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{(\log x)^a}{x^p}\,dx$ is improper integrable

Tags: improper-integrals

how to show $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{(\log x)^a}{x^p}dx$, if $p \gt 1$ and  $a \gt 0$???. I can show this is not improper integrable in case $p \lt  1 $, but I was stuck in showing the other case. Could you let me know how to handle it??

Comment: It is not integrable if $p<1$.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, I was wrong to post. I will edit! Thanks, but could you let me know how to show this integral is finite if $p >1$?

Comment: You can show that the integrand is dominated by $1/x^{p-\delta}$ for arbitrarily small $ \delta > 0 $ and then use the fact that $1/x^{p-\delta}$ is integrable for sufficiently small $\delta$ (provided $p>1$).

Comment: @derpy Actually, I tried to show that you mentioned but, I can't...

Comment: $$ x\mapsto e^u $$

Answer (score 1):

Do some *asymptotic analysis*:

Choose  $\varepsilon>0$ such that $1<q=p-\varepsilon$, and rewrite the integrand as
$$\frac{\log^ax}{x^p}=\frac{\log^ax}{x^\varepsilon}\frac 1{x^{q}}=o\Bigl(\frac1{x^q}\Bigr),$$
and the latter function has a convergent integral on $[1,\infty)$ since $q>1$.

Comment: could you explain more about the latter function ..??

Comment: What do you not  understand? Why the integral of $1/x^q$ converges?

Comment: I understand $\frac{1}{x^q}$ is convergent, but how do I think $\frac{\log^ax}{x^\varepsilon}$ ??

Comment: Using the *comparison test*: as the ratio tends to $0$ at $\infty$, it is $<1$ if $x$ is large enough, so the function is bounded from above by $\frac 1{x^q}$. (Actually, it is a basic result in asymptotic analysis).